# Why UIImageView get blank when I swipe back?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a `UICollectionView` in my `UIViewController`(wrapped in `UINavigationContoller`). In the `UICollectionViewCell`, I create a `UIImageView` with a gif url.(Using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher))

The imageView works as expected, but it's getting blank whenever I "try to" swipe back to previous `UIViewController`. And when I cancel the "swipe back gesture", the imageView shows the gif again.

Oddly enough, the imageView is not getting blank when I click the back indicator.

Also, if I set a static image to the imageView, the imageView does not get blank.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Here is a demo:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController2(), animated: true)
    }
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(snp_topLayoutGuideBottom)
            make.left.right.bottom.equalTo(view)
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController2: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "1")!, UIImage(named: "2")!]
        cell.imageView.startAnimating()
        return cell
    }
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        return view
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(contentView)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I think this is a `UIImageView` issue.

Comment: What do you mean getting blank?  If you're leaving the VC does it matter?

Comment: I am not leaving the VC, just try to swipe back and cancel.

Comment: How are you implementing the gif?

Comment: Maybe the gif that you are getting from a URL is loading in the `viewDidLoad()`, try it inside `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: I'm experiencing something very similar. It's during the swipe back that the image goes blank, but then returns if you decide not to swipe back and return the view to where it was. Not sure how to fix it, though.